# Round all MongoDB float values in a collection to 2 decimal places

Tags: mongodb

Is there a quick and easy way to tell Mongo that for properties that have values that are floats with over 10 decimal places that I do not care about that level of detail and would like all values to be rounded to 2 decimal places?

e.g., in collection `X` I have

`{'a': 13.4823423, 'b': 12.423424524342342}`

and many similar documents thousands of times over, and I want

`{'a': 13.48, 'b': 12.42}`

I know this is a failure on my end of inputting the data this way, and in my head the quick fix would be a python script to go over everything and round it, but my question is specifically **is there a built in Mongo command that handles cases like this really well?**. Thanks.

Comment: Let me know if you ever found an answer to that, i am facing the same problem

Comment: I ended up just manually doing it; it doesn't look like a built in function exists. However it wouldn't be too bad to write one (recursive function on any document that goes through every key/value, rounds, and re-applies recursively)

Comment: I think i will end up solving it via C#, by overwriting the Serialization method of the float attribute. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can use Math.round with Math.pow. For example, you can get 13.48 as

> Math.round(x['a'] * Math.pow(10,2)) * Math.pow(10, -2)

Not fancy, but workable.